# Retrieve and display images from MySQL database (with condition)

Tags: php, mysql, image, imageview

I'm having a problem on developing my website..

First, I have 2 tables:

1- **Products**: contains info. about the products & 2- **Images**: which contains product images.

The idea is that : I want to insert an image or two for a specified product and display that image for that product only..

In the mean time, I can insert images into the database and I can also display them.. but my issue is that when I try to do display.. the code retrieves all images from **Images** table..

**so my question:** how can I display image/s for only one product .. not all images in that table? I'm confused in how to make this condition.. need ur help guys  :?

Here's my code:

**File1: imageUpload.php**

```
<?php

if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db ("myDB");
$imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
$imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Images(imageType ,imageData, product_id)
    VALUES('{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}','{$_POST['memids']}')";
$current_id = mysql_query($sql) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Image Insert<br/>" .        

    mysql_error());
if(isset($current_id)) {
header("Location: listImages.php");
}
 }
}
?>


<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Upload Image</TITLE>
<link href="imageStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name="frmImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post"   
class="frmImageUpload">
<label>Upload Image File:</label><br/>
<input name="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" required/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" /><br><br>

</form>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**File2: listImages.php**

```
<?ob_start()?>

<?php


$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("myDB");
$sql = "SELECT imageId FROM Images
      ORDER BY imageId DESC"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>


<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>List BLOB Images</TITLE>
<link href="imageStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["imageId"]; ?> "width="200" /><br/>
<?php       
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
<?ob_flush()?>
```

**File3: imageView.php**

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("myDB") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_GET['image_id'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT imageType,imageData FROM Images WHERE imageId=" . $_GET['image_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Retrieving Image BLOB<br/>" . mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    header("Content-type: " . $row["imageType"]);
    echo $row["imageData"];
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: silly question, but are your ID's different in your database? As in is your index field auto incremented? so that when you select by imageId, that all ID's are diff.

Comment: First: beware of SQL-Injection, you get $_GET['image_id'] in from a real evil place and that could contain interesting stuff, really! I could not see where you try to restrict to one product, should you not get a product_id also into your request?

Comment: As @Eli said, check your `imageID` column in the database for duplicates.

Comment: I have checked ,, there is no duplicates.. because imageId is auto_increment in the database